# Launch a desktop application and Issue commands from a custom hyperlink,..difficult?

Tags: wpf, command, hyperlink

Okay,.. I'm looking into technologies for a 'Case Management' solution design at the moment and one of the requirements is to be able to receive an email from the system and have the user be able to jump straight to that case,..by id or something similar.

Many of the requirements fit well with a smart client architecture so I'm considering using WPF.  I have plenty of experience with WPF but I'm struggling to see how I could have the application launch and browse to the correct case by means of the user clicking the hyperlink.  I realise Silverlight is another option,..I'm mainly interested in how this could be done.

I've seen it done before.  LastFM for example have their links in the form 'LastFM://blahblahblah'. Spotify do the same thing too.

I always thought that was pretty clever but I've never understood how that works. Can anyone shed any light on how this works?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you would need to [associate your application with the custom protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Kent,..I reckon I must owe you about half my salary so far given how many of my questions you've answered inside 10 minutes.  Thanks for that. you're a legend.